# How to manually add legend to ggmap in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I am using `ggmap` to produce a map of Europe, on top of which I am plotting several points in certain colors. Now I would like to add a legend. So far, my code for plotting looks like this:

```
map <- get_map(location = "Europe", zoom = 3, color = "bw")
p <- ggmap(map)
p <- p + geom_point(data=d, aes(x=lon, y=lat),size=1.25, col="gray40")
p <- p + geom_point(data=d.stations1, aes(x=lon, y=lat),size=1.5,         col=colors[1])
p <- p + geom_point(data=d.stations2, aes(x=lon, y=lat),size=1.5, col=colors[2])
p <- p + geom_point(data=d.stations3, aes(x=lon, y=lat),size=1.5, col=colors[3])
p <- p + geom_point(data=d.reference.station, aes(x=lon, y=lat),size=1.5, col=color.ref)
p <- p + scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-25,62), expand = c(0, 0)) +  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(27,75), expand = c(0, 0)) + xlab("Longitude") +     ylab("Latitude")
ggplot_build(p)`
```

The objects `d.stations1`, `d.stations2` and `d.stations3` are subsets of the rows of d, with

```
d <- data.frame(st = stations.list, lat = latitudes, lon = longitudes)
```

Essentially, I plot all points in gray, and then plot certain subsets on top of that in previously chosen colors.

Now, I would like to have a legend next to the plots (preferably not on the map), with the colors explained for the points.

Some of the plotted points in d.stations1 also belong to d.stations2 and so on, so I am not sure how I can actually produce a working legend. I have tried

I have tried adding

```
p <- p + scale_color_manual(name = "Distance", labels = c(1:3), values = colors) + theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

but this gives an error (scale for colour already defined)

Comment: I'd appreciate a sample (i.e. minimal) dataset to experiment with.

Comment: Thanks, but I already solved the problem. Well not really solved, I just created a separate legend using the standard R plotting tools